# Defining a Casimir element

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, definition, lie-algebras, bilinear-form

**1. Context**.
Let $A$ be a $\mathbb K$-Frobenius algebra with Frobenius form $\kappa$.
Let $(l_i)_{i \in 1,..., N}$ be a basis of $A$.
Choose $(r_i)_{i \in 1,..., N}$ such that $\kappa (l_i, r_j)=\delta_{ij}$. Because $\kappa$ is non-degenerate, the familiy $(r_i)_{i \in 1,..., N}$ is $\mathbb K$-linearly independent, hence a basis. We call this pair of bases a pair of dual bases.

Define $C := \sum\limits_{i=1}^N l_i \otimes r_i \in A \otimes A$.
My lecture notes state:

> $C$ is a Casimir element, i.e. $aC=Ca$ for all $a \in A$.

The notes go on to mention that the notion of Casimir element is related to the Casimir effect in physics. However, they do not specify how.

**2. Questions**

- How is a Casimir element defined in the above context?
  I read the *wikipedia* and the *Encyclopedia of Mathematics* article on the Casimir element. I can see similarities between the above hints at a definition of $C$ and the construction presented under the subheading "Quadratic Casimir element" on wikipedia. However, on wikipedia a Casimir element is defined as "a certain distinguished element of the center of the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra." In the above context, however, $A \otimes A$ is not a universal enveloping algebra in general.
- How is the above Casimir element related to the Casimir effect? I could not find anything online. Even a reference would be appreciated.

Comment: An intuition that I find helpful: Consider an embedded circular string moving smoothly in some manifold.  If you regard the $l_i$ as states that the circular string might be in, then the elements of $A$ describe superpositions of those states.  If the circular string pinches into a figure of eight and splits into two circular strings, then multiplying by $C$ describes the resulting superpositions of pairs of states on the two new circular strings.  That is, if the initial string is in superposition of states $a$, then after splitting, the pair will be in superpositions of state $aC=Ca$.

Comment: @MatthewTowers Sorry for the imprecision. I changed it to "How is a Casimir element defined?"

Comment: I am sure your notes mention that $C$ is independent of the choice of basis elements.  One way to define it independently of  a basis is to use $\kappa$ to identify $A\otimes A$ with ${\rm End}_{\mathbb{K}}(A)$.  That is regard $a\otimes b$ as the linear map sending $c\mapsto a\kappa(b,c)$.  Then $C$ is just $1_A$.

Comment: @tkf The intuition might prove to be helpful, thanks. But at the moment I am still looking for a definition of a Casimir element. Something like "A Casimir element $C$ in a Frobenius algebra $A$ is ..." Is it just an element $C$ such that $aC=Ca$ for all $a \in A$? Or is it the tensor product of a pair of dual bases in the above manner?

Comment: I don't know about the terminology, but certainly the element $C$ you described is fundamental to $1+1$ dimensional topological quantum field theory for the reason I described, so it deserves its own name.  Also it certainly results from tensoring any pair of dual basis', so is canonical to the algebra, and has the property $aC=Ca$.  I have also heard $C$ referred to as "the canonical element".  Hopefully someone will be able to help more.